# Multiple group by

Tags: sql

I have an issue with a Sql statements.

I have the following lines with two rows (task|day) :

```
task1  Monday
task2  Sunday
task1  Monday
task1  Wednesday
```

I would like to have something like that in the end :

```
task1  Monday  2
task1  Wednesday  1
task2  Sunday  1
```

I tried this statements but I don't know how to add a second filter on the day row :

```
SELECT task 
FROM table 
GROUP BY task 
having count(task)>1
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TASK, DAY, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY TASK, DAY
```